# Equivalent expression "break bad" in Portuguese

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, localização

Used in a TV Series (Breaking Bad), the expression "break bad" meaning to challenge conventions, to defy authority and to skirt the edges of the law.

Does there exist any equivalent expression in Portuguese (Europe/Brazilian)?

---

Usado em uma série de TV (Breaking Bad), a expressão "break bad" significa desafiar o que é convencional, desafiar uma "autoridade" ou contornar "a lei".

Existe alguma expressão equivalente em Português (Europeu/Brasileiro)?

Comment: Boa pergunta, esta é daquelas expressões que prefiro manter na língua original.

Comment: Tenho a mesma opinião do Jorge

Comment: @LucasMotta não entendo muito de inglês (nem de Portugues), mas acho que não é um termo só ligado a "lei", mas sim a atitude boa e má, neste caso eu conheço um termo usado no Brasil ao menos que seja equivalente, mas eu postei e não respondi, tanto para dar a oportunidade de participação, quanto de alguém trazer uma resposta melhor.

Comment: @JorgeB. o mesmo que disse ao Lucas.

Comment: Qual é o termo?

Comment: @JorgeB. Acredito que seja "chutar o balde", tem outro, mas não me recordo.

Comment: Não me parece que seja a mesma coisa...

Comment: [Não é exactamente isso que "break bad" significa.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/174891/115443)

Comment: @JNat Talvez o programa de TV e os usuários do twitter estivessem enganados, mas na época (2013) me pareceu fazer sentido: http://noticias.r7.com/blogs/querido-leitor/como-seria-a-traducao-de-breaking-bad-no-brasil-as-respostas/2013/10/29/

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu ouvi isto em 2013 (quando vi a tv em canal aberto a primeira vez) em um programa de TV e no twitter

Comment: @VictorStafusa I guess there is no need to burninate the English tags; they should disappear once we have set up synonyms, right? The consensus on meta so far seems in favor of synonyms over burnination (as I think you know): http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1

Comment: @JorgeB. Talvez seja “chutamos o pau da barraca”, “jogamos tudo pro alto", "da água para o vinho", ao menos foram os únicos termos que encontrei http://inglesnapontadalingua.com.br/2015/01/o-que-significa-breaking-bad.html

Comment: @JNat Eu vi o seu link, mas não me parece tão longe, por exemplo `to go downhill` seria algo bem próximo, já que quando "chutamos o baude" ou o "chutamos o pau da barraca" é quando começamos a fazer as coisas de maneira errada ou sem se importar com as consequências, devido a algum acontecimento. Isto pode ser algo talvez no popular que tenha mudado de sentido. Não sei ao certo.

Comment: "Química do mal"

Comment: Ultrapassando o limite? Aqui em Portugal chama se: Ruptura total

Comment: @JorgeB. então quem chuta o balde (ou o pau da barraca) são pessoas que estão em uma situação que as leva ao limite.

Comment: Nunca tinha visto essa pergunta, mas lá no stack de english learners tem um tópico que fiz a um bom tempo atrás
http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/what-does-the-slang-breaking-bad-actually-mean

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio obrigado vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

## Chutando o Balde

Ou ainda

## Chutando o Pau da Barraca (Brasil)

É um dos casos clássicos de [*phrasal verbs*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb), cuja tradução literal não faz sentido (ficaria algo como "quebrando feio" no literal).

Comment: Chutando o balde também é no Brasil, concordo contigo. O sentido de ambos seria por exemplo quando você está fazendo uma tarefa usando o balde ou preparando a barraca e tudo da errado, então você fica irritado e chuta as coisas. Ao menos é o que me parece.

Comment: Contornar a lei é "dar um jeitinho". Interessante, segundo o google translator "breaking bad" seria "liberando o mal".